# Extracting Day/Hour/Minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have the following code which is working, however how do I get the terminal minutes to show the output as Day, Hour, Minute?  If this cannot be done, is it possible to add a +1 on the time which would indicate it's the following day?

The problem I am having is that when our orders run past 23.59 PM, the system is not displaying the correct format because of the 24 hour time period.

[image]
I am stumped and hope I am not confusing matters.

```
SELECT FOLIO_NUMBER, TERMINAL_NAME,
  format((START_LOAD_TIME - ORDER_ENTRY_TIME), 'HH:mm') AS STAGING_MINUTES, 
  format((TERM_END_LOAD_TIME - START_LOAD_TIME), 'HH:mm') AS LOADING_MINUTES,
  format((TERM_END_LOAD_TIME - ORDER_ENTRY_TIME), 'HH:mm') AS TERMINAL_MINUTES 
FROM ORDERS  
JOIN TERMINAL_OWNER ON ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = TERMINAL_OWNER.TERMINAL_ID
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2012

Comment: Can you do the select without the string formatting and then do the formatting in the front end where it is displayed? Usually, programming languages which deal with user interfaces have simpler ways of doing what you want compared to SQL.

Comment: The terminal minutes are calculated by subtracting term_end_load_time from the order_entry time (Start to finish).  However they want the staging / loading headers to only show the hour (time) and the terminal minutes to show the day, hour and minutes if an order goes over a 24 hour period.

Comment: What are `TERM_END_LOAD_TIME` and `ORDER_ENTRY_TIME`? You can't use subtraction with `time`.

Comment: @ArriBenson you explained that in the question text. What are the *field types*? They can't be `time`. If you subtract `datetime` fields, you get back a `datetime`

Comment: @ArriBenson The image looks like SSMS - which is not intended to be for production. Is there an another program involved for the end-users?

Comment: Are you saying that I must use date instead of time?

Comment: @ArriBenson I'm saying that you aren't using time right now. If you did, you'd gett a syntax error saying  `Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator.` Don't post images. Post the *field types*.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused here - If you mean the field types as in the headers, they are Start_Load_Time, Order_Entry_time, Term_End_Load_Time, Folio_Number.

Comment: @ArriBenson if the fields are `datetime` you can use `select format(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME  - ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, 'dd\ HH:mm')` to format the difference

Comment: @ArriBenson databases have no headers. They have *tables* with *columns*. Those columns have types that control what you can or can't do with their values. What columns do you see when you expand the `Columns` node under the `ORDERS` table in the Object Explorer? What are the types of the fields?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e5a4474-31b8-4316-8a34-1e4a5572fb49/date-difference-in-dayshours-minutes-and-seconds?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
Declare @theMinutes Varchar(10)
Set @theMinutes = '19:25' 

declare @totMintute int
Select    
  @totMintute = (Cast(
  Cast(left(@theMinutes,charindex(':',@theMinutes)-1) as Int) * 60
  + Cast(substring(@theMinutes,charindex(',',@theMinutes)+4,len(@theMinutes)) as Int)  
as Int ) * 60) / 60

--For 12 hour 1 days
Select @totMintute / 720 as NoDays  -- 720 minutes per day 
       , (@totMintute % 720) / 60 as NoHours -- modulo 720 
       , (@totMintute % 60) as NoMinutes -- modulo 60

--For 24 hour 1 days
Select @totMintute / 1440 as NoDays  -- 1440 minutes per day 
       , (@totMintute % 1440) / 60 as NoHours -- modulo 1440 
       , (@totMintute % 60) as NoMinutes -- modulo 60
```

The output will look like as shown below.

[image]

You can convert this query data source table as shown below.

```
Create table #Temp (MinValue Varchar(8))
insert into #Temp Values ('19:25')

Select TotMinute / 720 as NoDays  -- 1440 minutes per day 
       , (TotMinute % 720) / 60 as NoHours -- modulo 1440 
       , (TotMinute % 60) as NoMinutes -- modulo 60
from(
select 
(Cast(
  Cast(left(MinValue,charindex(':',MinValue)-1) as Int) * 60
  + Cast(substring(MinValue,charindex(',',MinValue)+4,len(MinValue)) as Int)
as Int ) * 60) / 60  as TotMinute
from #Temp
)a
```

You can find the live demo [here](https://rextester.com/VTGXFA7483).

Comment: Thanks, how do I add the results to display as one instead of 2 seperate windows?

Comment: @ArriBenson I didn't get you? I have run two query but you have to run only one so it will come only one window.

Comment: yes, at the moment the query runs but displays the results separately like in your screenshot.

Comment: I think You can use like a + b + c as d. Here a is NoDays, b is No hour ...

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @INT INT

SET @INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND,GETDATE(),GETDATE()+1)

select 
convert(varchar(10), (@INT/86400)) + ':' + 
convert(varchar(10), ((@INT%86400)/3600)) + ':'+
convert(varchar(10), (((@INT%86400)%3600)/60)) + ':'+
convert(varchar(10), (((@INT%86400)%3600)%60)) as 'DD:HH:MM:SS'
```

Courtesy of Nat-MS. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e5a4474-31b8-4316-8a34-1e4a5572fb49/date-difference-in-dayshours-minutes-and-seconds?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should remove the need to identify days/hours in the SQL Output and just get the difference in minutes, which you can then work with in your application layer.

Take [this sample code](https://rextester.com/VQZLK20204):

```
create table #orders (
    FOLIO_NUMBER int,
    START_LOAD_TIME datetime,
    ORDER_ENTRY_TIME datetime,
    TERM_END_LOAD_TIME datetime
)

insert into #orders (FOLIO_NUMBER,START_LOAD_TIME,ORDER_ENTRY_TIME,TERM_END_LOAD_TIME)
values (1, getdate(),getdate() - 1,getdate() + 1)

select *, 
    datediff(mi, ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, START_LOAD_TIME) AS STAGING_MINUTES,
    datediff(mi, START_LOAD_TIME, TERM_END_LOAD_TIME) AS LOADING_MINUTES,
    datediff(mi, ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, TERM_END_LOAD_TIME) AS TERMINAL_MINUTES
from #orders

drop table #orders
```

This will output the minutes difference between the events:

```
FOLIO_NUMBER    STAGING_MINUTES LOADING_MINUTES TERMINAL_MINUTES
1               1440            1440            2880
```

You can then perform some simple maths with these values to extract, days, hours and minutes.

Comment: your solution above is idea by showing the minutes, however  the output is showing as you indicate above a single line result, my issue is that I require the information per folio number as shown above.  I would expect to see the same number of lines as there are folios i.e. 10 folios = 10 lines on the result.  Please advise if you can?

Comment: @ArriBenson this is just a sample with one row, it would show multiple rows if there was more data present.

Comment: did you see my screenshot - there are multiple lines and when I run your query it only displays 1 line?

Comment: @ArriBenson it's a sample piece of code... if you created some SQL I could have copied and pasted, I would have added more rows, but instead you posted an image which I can't use to generate some sample data.